# CDK v2 update resulting in deployment error with Circle CI CI/CD pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk, circleci, aws-ssm

I have updated my cdk from version 1 to version 2, when I tried to do this locally using `npm run cdk -- deploy --context awsEnv=dev --all --profile=dev`, this works flawlessly.

However when the Circle CI CI/CD pipeline tries to deploy in the same dev environment, it throws an error

```
  User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxx:assumed-role/*******************************************************/jatinmehrotra is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter on resource: arn:aws:ssm:**************:xxxxx:parameter/cdk-bootstrap/xxxxxxxxx/version because no identity-based policy allows the ssm:GetParameter action
```

SO basically Circle CI CI/CD pipeline for deployment assumes the roles and create temporary credentials using `aws sts assume role` command.

Note:- after updating to cdk v2 I can see a new role, which has the same name as the bootstrap ssm parameter. Does that have to do something with error?

As of now, I think the assume role credentials (even though it has sufficient permissions) are not able to access the bootstrap parameter.

Comment: I believe I saw a bug report on something similar to this a while back with updates. You may need to manually update the role for your pipeline to have that access.

Comment: Is it possible to share that bug report? Because when I updated the role manually it worked, so I am just wondering why CDK didn't update the role automatically with appropriate permissions.

Comment: I am not able to find it unfortunately. I belive the bug was due to something when migrating from v1 to v2 and after a manual fix is not a problem (and not a problem for any stack begun in v2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some troubleshooting and carefully reading the error logs, **`i manually updated the role's permission with full SSM parameters permission whose credentials are being used to deploy the resources.`**

This resolved the issue.